# When does IIS recycle the worker process?

Tags: iis-6, worker-process, application-pool

When I setup an application pool for my web app in IIS 6 it defaults the worker process to recycle in 1740 minutes (29 hours).

Does this recycle happen even if there is activity on the web site or only if there is inactivity for 29 hours?

Comment: Good question, but no answers below really answer your question. I'm still confused. If a recycle takes place after 29 hours, will it allow requests to finish or not?

Comment: @JL: This may be helpful: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/david.wang/archive/2005/09/19/why-do-i-lose-asp-session-state-on-iis6.aspx Basically, IIS will continue to process requests (assuming your recycling is overlapped), but the application will lose user session state unless specially designed to save the state to disk.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This depends on how your worker process recycling is configured.  There are several ways to configure it and each one has different implications.

- Elapsed Time: In this mode the process will recycle after a period of time no matter how many requests come in
- After a request threshold is reached
- On Demand through the IIS Manager Tool

You can find detailed information on this topic at the following link

- http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc778695(WS.10).aspx

Answer (score 4):

[Read the Fine Manual](http://www.bing.com/search?q=worker+process+recycling&FORM=QBHP)

in particular, [Configuring Worker Processes for Recycling (IIS 6.0)](http://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/WindowsServer2003/Library/IIS/3ee19598-ec90-4570-a4a5-d93a24400b99.mspx?mfr=true)

Comment: Someone downvoted me for providing a direct link to the manufacturer documentation that describes in detail when IIS worker processes get recycled?